# Redis return the error when i try to insert data to redis on window

Tags: php, database, redis, predis, nosql

I installed Redis v.3.2.100 with default setting on windows 10. I run a php code that does simple hmget/hmset command, when i insert  data to redis database. it failed with error message:

This is the error message in redis log:

> [8912] 19 Sep 16:03:25.057 # Can't save in background: fork: Unknown error
>   [8912] 19 Sep 16:03:31.073 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
>   [8912] 19 Sep 16:03:31.078 # BeginForkOperation: system error caught. error code=0x0000007b, message=Problem creating slave process: invalid argument
>
> [8912] 19 Sep 16:03:31.079 # Can't save in background: fork: Unknown
>   error 
>   [8912] 19 Sep 16:03:37.099 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds.
>   Saving... [8912] 19 Sep 16:03:37.103 # BeginForkOperation: system error caught. error code=0x0000007b, message=Problem creating slave process: invalid argument

[This is the error message in redis log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pUeQ.jpg)
How can i fix this error? please I actually need some help. Also the following question has the same problem, it is abandoned long time ago with no answers and most probably no attempts to solve the problem.